# How does Spring Data JPA query specific SQL database tables?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Hi im new to using JPA and specifically Spring Data JPA.  Im used to using JDBC to make direct queries to a SQL database within Java code.  Its straight forward and easy to understand but very verbose.

Using Spring Data JPA and I understand its standard to create an entity class to model a SQL table within Java and use a repository class to query that model.  What I dont completely understand is how Spring data JPA retrieves data from the SQL server to populate entity classes.  Take for example I have 3 tables in my SQL server: shoppers, businesses, and owners.  If I made corresponding entities to those tables how does JPA immediately know which table im specifically referring to?  You can name the entity the same as the table but it doesnt seem concrete.

Comment: when you define an Entity you need to say which table is mapping, then JPA know exactly which table are you talking about in the repositories, also with relationships OneToMany (for instance) JPA can know the joins with other tables and make more complex queries

Answer (score 1):

It will create a table with a name corresponding to your class name. You can change the default mapping with the `@Table` annotation.